# Удаление текста в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Нужно сделать так, чтобы через время(использую модуль time) сообщения исчезали/удалялись.
Подскажите пожалуйста строку для удаления

обрывок кода:

```
def click1():
    number = randint(1, 1)
    for i in cu.execute(f"SELECT cash FROM user WHERE login = '{user_login}'"):
        cashe = i[0]
    if number == 1:
        cu.execute(f"UPDATE user SET cash = {1 + cashe} WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
        text.insert(INSERT, f"\nВаше число кликов: {cashe}")
        db.commit()
```

Comment: Нет, не из базы. Нужно чтобы удалялась данная строка: `text.insert(INSERT, f"\nВаше число кликов: {cashe}")`

Comment: Для удаления сообщений из текстового поля Text нужно использовать метод delete (см. https://learn4kid-python.firebaseapp.com/tkinter_2/tkinter_text/#%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B), но для этого нужно знать индексы начала/конца сообщения

Comment: @insolor Понял, не подскажите пожалуйста как узнать индекс?

Comment: Ну например, если нужно удалить первую строку, пишите `text.delete(1.0, 2.0)`. По той ссылке есть эта информация.

Comment: @insolor Благодарен вам. Отпишитесь в ответе, дабы я ответил его верным

Comment: Кстати, `text.insert(INSERT, f"\nВаше число кликов: {cashe}")` делает вставку туда, где в данный момент находится курсор. Если пользователь кликнет в середину текста, то текст будет добавляться туда. Лучше использовать END, тогда текст будет добавляться в конец.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для удаления конкретных строк их поля `Text` нужно вызвать метод `delete` с указанием индексов удаляемых строк. Например, чтобы удалить первую строку:

```
text.delete(1.0, 2.0)
```

(удалить от нулевого символа 1-й строки до нулевого символа 2-й строки)

Для удаления последней строки можно использовать текстовые индексы:

```
text.delete("end-1l", "end")  # end-1l - минус одна строка от конца
```